# Unable To Import Blank Date Fields Into MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to query DB1 and populate all entries into DB2 within my application, however, I am having an issue where DB1 is returning a blank entry for a datetime field.

When my application tries to read in the data, I get an exception: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid

```
Dim tmp_closed_at_Date As Date
Dim closed_at_Date As String

tmp_closed_at_Date = dt.Rows(i)("closed_at")
If Not tmp_closed_at_Date = Nothing Then closed_at_Date = tmp_closed_at_Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

I'm not sure if my code is even correct, but I am finding that when I return my data into a datatable, it is converting the date format from 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' to 'dd\MM\yyyy HH:mm:ss' so I am having to convert the date back through a string to allow population into DB2.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Due to DB1 being a 3rd party database, I cannot make any modification to the table structure.

Comment: compare the value to dbnull first before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the value in the row first to DBNULL before assignment:

```
Dim tmp_closed_at_Date As Date
Dim closed_at_Date As String


If Not IsDbNull(dt.Rows(i)("closed_at")) Then  
     tmp_closed_at_Date = directcast(dt.Rows(i)("closed_at"), datetime)
     closed_at_Date = tmp_closed_at_Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
End If
```